# How do I add exclusions to Microsoft Security Essentials (MSE, Windows 7) through a powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I need to be able to add antivirus exclusions to MSE on Windows 7 using a powershell (or cmd) script. If I use:

```
Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "C:\Temp"
Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "C:\Users\ME\Desktop"
```

in powershell (which works for Windows 10 Windows Defender) I get this error:

```
The term 'Add-MpPreference' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:17
+ Add-MpPreference <<<<  -ExclusionPath "C:\Temp"
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Add-MpPreference:String) [], 
CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to do it in PowerShell why did you tag the question with **batch-file** and **vbscript**?

Comment: or with a batch file

Comment: Please copy and paste the error message into the question. SO does not have seers to reveal such information.

Comment: Are you running any other anti-virus software such as McAfee or Symantec?

Comment: If I was indeed a seer, i would say you getting some error like `The term 'Add-MpPreference' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file ...bla bla`.

Comment: yes I don't think `Add-MpPreference` works with MSE, let alone windows 7. But does anyone know what to do for Windows 7 MSE?

Comment: No @lit, I am not running any other AV i'm only running MSE

Comment: Please read the error message; particularly the last line. `+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: @RohinSidharth You've earned the `● Seer` badge (First error message guessed)  :)